# WSO2 Stratos - Multi-tenant application development

Tags: wso2

I am exploring the product WSO2 stratos ,watched some of the webinar recordings. I would like to create an application and expose it as SAAS.One of the webex recordings cover this in detail , but it is not explaining the multi-tenancy on data storage. Is there any tutorial available for the same ? I would like to use shared schema for data storage. What kind of database can i use for this ( For eg: MySql,MongoDB,Cassandra etc ) Is it possible to use some frame works like Athena ? I am just trying to do a kind of POC and then i need to decide whether this platform really fits for the application that i am thinking to build

Answer (score 0):

You can create databases through WSO2 Storage Server in StratosLive which can be accessed via storage.stratoslive.wso2.com. You need to create a database and attach a user to it. Then you can access that database from your webapp (you will get a jdbc url) as you do it in normal cases. Also, you can create Cassandra keyspaces in the Storage Server. But we dont have the MongoDB support at the moment. There is no documentation on this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. Multi-tenant data architecture is up to the user to decide. [This white paper from Microsoft explains multi-tenant data architecture nicely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). The whitepaper however is written assuming you're using an RDBMS. I haven't played around with Athena so it's difficult to say how it'll map with what Stratos provides. The data architecture might be different when you're using a NoSQL DB and different DBs have different ways of filtering a set of data by a given tenant (or an ID). So probably going by the whitepaper it'll map to,

Different DBs -> Different keyspaces
Different tabeles -> Different column families
Shared schema -> Shared column family

Better to define your application characteristics before hand and then choose an appropriate DB